# Calculate the average value for each column in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I have a table:

| Id | Price | Quantity | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 2 | 20 |
| 2 | 5 | 5 | 25 |
| 3 | 15 | 2 | 30 |

I need to calculate the result as:

- `AvgPrice`: The average value of column `Price`
- `MinQty`: The minimal value of column `Quantity`
- `TotalAmount`: sum value of column `Amount`

Comment: Simple or weighted average price?

Comment: @david, Hi david welcome to stackoverflow, have you tried `AVG`, `SUM`,`MIN` aggregate functions in SQL

Comment: That should be simple,
`SELECT AVG(Price) AS AvgPrice, MIN(Quantity) AS MinQty, SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount FROM YourTableName;`

Do you face further problems than this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AVG, SUM, MIN [aggregate functions in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
SELECT AVG(Price) AS AvgPrice, 
MIN(Quantity) AS MinQty, 
SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM table_name;
```

This shall return you output as :

```
AvgPrice    MinQty    TotalAmount
---------------------------------
10          2         75
```